# Style loading issue, screen flickering in Next.js with styled-components and SWC

Tags: next.js, styled-components, swc

It seems like a silly problem because it happens within milliseconds, but it's annoying. When loading and reloading the page, it's just like the HTML, within milliseconds the styles are loaded.

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74242349/styles-take-time-to-load-next-js/74244275#74244275) answer your question?